# Como manejar los fetch.type lazy

Tags: java, oracle

Tengo un problema con un campo de un objeto el cual tiene fetch = FetchType.LAZY, me dijeron que para solucionarlo debia usar un DTO sin embargo aunque hice el DTO sigo teniendo el error, probablemente implemente mal el dto pero en este momento me encuentro estancado porque toda la investigacion del error que he hecho me ha dejado en las mismas, porque la manera en que lo solucionan no aplica a mi proyecto, podria cambiar la palabra LAZY por EAGER y estaria todo solucionado pero esta solucion no aplica.

Esta es la excepcion que me lanza el programa

```
Exception Description: An attempt was made to traverse a relationship using indirection that had a null Session. This often occurs when a n entity with an uninstantiated LAZY relationship is serialized and that lazy relationship is traversed after serialization. To avoid this issue, ins tantiate the LAZY relationship prior to serialization.
```

Otra solucion que vi fue que tenia que instanciar lo que iba retornar la consulta antes de serializarla y entonces usaban un .size() pero esto tampoco me funciono y no lo puedo utilizar porque en el sitio donde estan las consultas no son returnlist ni cosas asi, son namedqueries.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680490/ejb-exception-an-attempt-was-made-to-traverse-a-relationship-using-indirection

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826864/lazy-relationship-instantiation-issue-in-glassfish
Otros decian que utilizar Hibernate.initialize() pero tampoco estoy usando hibernate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875717/prevent-lazy-relationship-exception

Estoy un poco perdido con este error y la verdad no encuentro una guia clara de como hacer un DTO para solucionar esto, cualquier tipo de ayuda es apreciada, quedo atento.

Este es el codigo del DTO que hice:

```
public class MsObjetoRestDTO implements Serializable {

    private Long objecodi;
    private String objeacti;
    private String objedesc;
    private Date objefsys;
    private String objenomb;
    private String objelogi;
    private String objefsysS;

    // Atributos del MsTipoObjeto que es un atributo del MsObjeto

    private Long tiobcodi;
    private String tiobacti;
    private String tiobdesc;
    private Date tiobfsys;
    private String tioblogi;
    private String tiobnomb;
    private String tiobfsysS;

    public static List<MsObjetoRestDTO> msObjetoListAMsObjetoRestDTOList(List<MsObjeto> lMsObjetos) {
        List<MsObjetoRestDTO> lMsObjetosDTO = new ArrayList<MsObjetoRestDTO>();
        if (lMsObjetos != null) {
            for (MsObjeto msObjeto : lMsObjetos) {
                MsObjetoRestDTO msObjetoRestDTO = new MsObjetoRestDTO();
                msObjetoRestDTO.setObjecodi((msObjeto.getObjecodi() != null) ? msObjeto.getObjecodi() : null);
                msObjetoRestDTO.setObjeacti((msObjeto.getObjeacti() != null) ? msObjeto.getObjeacti() : null);
                msObjetoRestDTO.setObjedesc((msObjeto.getObjedesc() != null) ? msObjeto.getObjedesc() : null);
                msObjetoRestDTO.setObjefsys((msObjeto.getObjefsys() != null) ? msObjeto.getObjefsys() : null);
                msObjetoRestDTO.setObjenomb((msObjeto.getObjenomb() != null) ? msObjeto.getObjenomb() : null);
                msObjetoRestDTO.setObjelogi((msObjeto.getObjelogi() != null) ? msObjeto.getObjelogi() : null);
                msObjetoRestDTO.setObjefsysS((msObjeto.getObjefsysS() != null) ? msObjeto.getObjefsysS() : null);
                System.out.println(msObjetoRestDTO.toString());

                // Atributos del MsTipoObjeto
                System.out.println("El tamano de la lista: " + lMsObjetos.size());

                msObjetoRestDTO.setTiobcodi((msObjeto.getMsTipoObjeto().getTiobcodi() != null) ? msObjeto.getMsTipoObjeto().getTiobcodi(): null);
                msObjetoRestDTO.setTiobacti((msObjeto.getMsTipoObjeto().getTiobacti() != null) ? msObjeto.getMsTipoObjeto().getTiobacti(): null);
                msObjetoRestDTO.setTiobdesc((msObjeto.getMsTipoObjeto().getTiobdesc() != null) ? msObjeto.getMsTipoObjeto().getTiobdesc(): null);
                msObjetoRestDTO.setTiobfsys((msObjeto.getMsTipoObjeto().getTiobfsys() != null) ? msObjeto.getMsTipoObjeto().getTiobfsys(): null);
                msObjetoRestDTO.setTioblogi((msObjeto.getMsTipoObjeto().getTioblogi() != null) ? msObjeto.getMsTipoObjeto().getTioblogi(): null);
                msObjetoRestDTO.setTiobnomb((msObjeto.getMsTipoObjeto().getTiobnomb() != null) ? msObjeto.getMsTipoObjeto().getTiobnomb(): null);
                msObjetoRestDTO.setTiobfsysS((msObjeto.getMsTipoObjeto().getTiobfsysS() != null) ? msObjeto.getMsTipoObjeto().getTiobfsysS(): null);

                System.out.println("Despues del set tipoobjeto" + msObjetoRestDTO.toString());
                lMsObjetosDTO.add(msObjetoRestDTO);
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("El objeto esta nulo");
        }

        return lMsObjetosDTO;
    }

    public Long getObjecodi() {
        return objecodi;
    }

    public void setObjecodi(Long objecodi) {
        this.objecodi = objecodi;
    }

    public String getObjeacti() {
        return objeacti;
    }

    public void setObjeacti(String objeacti) {
        this.objeacti = objeacti;
    }

    public String getObjedesc() {
        return objedesc;
    }

    public void setObjedesc(String objedesc) {
        this.objedesc = objedesc;
    }

    public Date getObjefsys() {
        return objefsys;
    }

    public void setObjefsys(Date objefsys) {
        this.objefsys = objefsys;
    }

    public String getObjenomb() {
        return objenomb;
    }

    public void setObjenomb(String objenomb) {
        this.objenomb = objenomb;
    }

    public String getObjelogi() {
        return objelogi;
    }

    public void setObjelogi(String objelogi) {
        this.objelogi = objelogi;
    }

    public String getObjefsysS() {
        return objefsysS;
    }

    public void setObjefsysS(String objefsysS) {
        this.objefsysS = objefsysS;
    }

    // Getters y Setters de los atributos del MsTipoObjeto

    public Long getTiobcodi() {
        return tiobcodi;
    }

    public void setTiobcodi(Long tiobcodi) {
        this.tiobcodi = tiobcodi;
    }

    public String getTiobacti() {
        return tiobacti;
    }

    public void setTiobacti(String tiobacti) {
        this.tiobacti = tiobacti;
    }

    public String getTiobdesc() {
        return tiobdesc;
    }

    public void setTiobdesc(String tiobdesc) {
        this.tiobdesc = tiobdesc;
    }

    public Date getTiobfsys() {
        return tiobfsys;
    }

    public void setTiobfsys(Date tiobfsys) {
        this.tiobfsys = tiobfsys;
    }

    public String getTioblogi() {
        return tioblogi;
    }

    public void setTioblogi(String tioblogi) {
        this.tioblogi = tioblogi;
    }

    public String getTiobnomb() {
        return tiobnomb;
    }

    public void setTiobnomb(String tiobnomb) {
        this.tiobnomb = tiobnomb;
    }

    public String getTiobfsysS() {
        return tiobfsysS;
    }

    public void setTiobfsysS(String tiobfsysS) {
        this.tiobfsysS = tiobfsysS;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MsObjetoRestDTO [objecodi=" + objecodi + ", objeacti=" + objeacti + ", objedesc=" + objedesc
                + ", objefsys=" + objefsys + ", objenomb=" + objenomb + ", objelogi=" + objelogi + ", objefsysS="
                + objefsysS + ", tiobcodi=" + tiobcodi + "]";
    }

}
```

El recibe una lista de Objetos y los pasa a una lista de ObjetosDTO el problema es que igual al hacer esto

```
msObjetoRestDTO.setTiobcodi((msObjeto.getMsTipoObjeto().getTiobcodi() != null) ? msObjeto.getMsTipoObjeto().getTiobcodi(): null);
```

El programa se revienta porque no puede acceder a esa propiedad msObjeto.getMsTipoObjeto().getALGO

Comment: Si no muestras el código que tienes hasta ahora es un poco difícil ayudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso es porque la transacción de JPA ya a terminado, entonces si haces un get de una relación que no obtuviste mientras la transacción estaba activa obtienes ese error, por ejemplo: Si tenemos una entidad empleado que tiene una relación Lazy de uno a muchos con Permiso:

```
EntityManager em = createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
Empleado empleado = em.find(Empleado.class, id);
empleado.getPermisos.size();
em.close();
return empleado;
```

como puede ver mientras la transacción no haya terminado puede llamar tantas relaciones como quieras y luego retornar el objeto del cual llamaste las relaciones que necesitas, el único inconveniente es si el objeto permisos tiene una relación detalle, en ese caso debes recorrer la lista con un FOR para llamar a la relación detalle de cada objeto dentro de la lista, esta opcion no es la mas optima porque si tienes 1 empleado y 6 permisos obtendrás 1 + 6 consultas SQL.

Otra opción es utilizar JPQL en el cual utilizas JOIN FETCH por ejemplo:

```
Query query = entitymanager.createQuery( "Select e from Empleado e JOIN FETCH e.permisos where e.id = :id" );
query.setParameter("id", 1204);
List<Empleado> list = query.getResultList( );
```

En este caso debes ejecutar un JOIN FECH para cada relación que vayas a necesitar, utilizando este método JPA puede optimizar el query y en una solo consulta SQL obtendrá los datos.

Answer (score 0):

Al final estaba todo bien, solo que tenia la clase en el paquete DTO equivocado (porque estoy trabajando con 3 proyectos diferentes que estan relacionados y cada uno tiene su paquete de DTOs), por lo que se estaba ejecutando lo que tengo dentro de mi clase MsObjetoRestDTO despues de que la conexion LAZY se cerrara entonces por eso no estaba logrando nada. Solo dejo esto por si acaso alguien le sucede verificar esto tambien.